# Report Header/Footer and SubReport

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have created a report (`JasperReports`) that contains `Page Header`, `Detail`, and `Page Footer` bands. The `Page Header` and `Page Footer` contain static content to compose a header and footer that should be printed on each page.

I want the `Detail` in a separate file (`SubReport`) so that I can update `Page Header` and `Page Footer` without having to make the same updates to multiple reports.

There is a `SubReport` in the `Detail` band.  The `SubReport` has a link to a database and displays records, but does not need any information from the report.  The records are displayed when you view the `SubReport` individually, and the `SubReport` is linked, but nothing is displayed in the main report, and the resulting document is 84 pages.  I don't know why the result is 84 pages.  The `SubReport` I am currently using is only 24 pages.

I was able to get static content to show by selecting "All Sections, No Detail" in the properties, but with an SQL Query in the `SubReport`, there should be data to display.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You should post the main report and subreport (*jrxml* files)

Comment: The _SubReport_ is not connected to a public server, but it shouldn't matter.  I just want to insert a _SubReport_ and have it maintain its original behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After viewing this link: [`http://salilstock.blogspot.ca/2012/06/jasper-subreport-modularize-jasper.html`](http://salilstock.blogspot.ca/2012/06/jasper-subreport-modularize-jasper.html), I attempted to insert the header and footer as `SubReports` in my main report.  This approach seems promising.